# How to get the size of a vector in a JSON in the shell script?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, count, jq

I would like to get the size of a vector in a JSON in the shell script but I'm only getting the size of each vector string, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

j='{"Names": { "names": ["marry", "jason", "frank","kelly"] }}'

echo "$j" | jq -r ".Names | .names[] | length"
```

The output is :

```
5
4
5
4
```

But i want to get 4 that is the amount of items in the vector.

Comment: Your output does not match your input: how are you getting length "4" for strings "jason" and "kelly"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo "$j" | jq '.Names | .names | length'
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: What does `jq` stand for?

Comment: @EPo, notice "jq" in the list of tags under the question? Click it.